# How to pass 2 different types into a function param in c#?

Tags: c#

In c# if I have this

```
private void Run(Web site) {
    site.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
}

private void Run(ListItem folder) {
    folder.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
}
```

How can I instead make 1 function that can accept either `Site` or `Folder`?

Comment: Use an interface it's the best way for these types of questions.

Comment: You seem to be adding a lot of comments to answers that should have been in the question. Add all your constraints and why you cant use common approaches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Site` and `Folder` are classes that you've created, then you can create a common interface which those classes inherit from. For example:

```
public interface IBreakable
{
    void break();
}

public class Folder : IBreakable 
{
    public void break() { /* implementation here*/ }
}

public class Site : IBreakable 
{
    public void break() { /* implementation here*/ }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void Run(IBreakable breakable)
{
    breakable.break();
}
```

**Edit**

Here's a solution based on reflection, although this is not ideal.

```
void Run(object obj)
{
    MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("break");

    if (!(method is null))
    {
        method.Invoke(obj, new object[] {});
    }
}
```

**Given**

```
public class Foo
{
    public void break() {Console.WriteLine("Foo");}
}

public class Bar
{
    public void break() {Console.WriteLine("Bar");}
}

public class Bad
{
    public void NotBreak() {Console.WriteLine("Bad");}
}
```

**Usage**

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
Bad bad = new Bad();

Run(foo);
Run(bar);
Run(bad);
```

**Output**

> Foo

> Bar

Comment: The 2 classes come from an SDK though so I can't make it implement it.

Comment: @omega Are you able to provide the SDK details. It might be the case that they do have a common interface/base class. I'll provide another solution using reflection.

Comment: The SDK is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`

Comment: @omega See my edit. Also worth noting that the docs for `Folder` and `Site` have a common inheritance on `ClientObject`. Maybe `ClientObject` has the method you're wanting to use.

Comment: I figured it out  using `SecurableObject` instead, it supported most of the common methods, and then had to use reflection for the last one.

Answer (score 2):

As a later answer from @Pedro pointed out, those specific classes derive from a common ancestor, and that would be the preferred option. Assuming you did not have that option:

You can use the C# dynamic type (sorry if that is not the latest doc, I couldn't find a newer one):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Example:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = new Bar();
        DoSomething(foo);
        DoSomething(bar);
    }

    private static void DoSomething<T>(T someObjectWithDoMethod)
    {
        ((dynamic)someObjectWithDoMethod).Do();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
  public void Do() { Console.WriteLine("Foo is doing something"); }
}

public class Bar
{
  public void Do() { Console.WriteLine("Bar is doing something"); }
}
```

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MShLK5

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to other answers, `Web` and `ListItem` are types defined in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`.

Checking the SDK docs, both types derive from [SecurableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544927(v=office.15)) where the [BreakRoleInheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee545470(v=office.15)) method is defined.

That being the case, all you need to do is define one method that takes a `SecurableObject` object as an input:

```
public void Run(SecurableObject item)
{
    item.BreakRoleInheritance();
}
```

And you should be able to pass a `Web` and a `ListItem` to this same method.

Comment: It didn't have .Update() so I had to use reflection there

Comment: @omega I'm glad you were able to figure it out. Just an advice, make sure you include as much detail as possible to the question itself, for instance in the question there is no mention of an `.Update()` method, so I had no idea you needed that when I wrote my answer.